# JSON: export file from template with a JSON extension

Tags: json

I'm using JSON from Rob Sanchez, it's working fine.

The template create a file, but what is the solution for the template save the file with a json extension instead of .html or .js ??

Comment: Stupid question. Is not a flat file, so it's saves as html format. I've just installed VL File Generator, but i've contacted the author because it's not working. Would be nice if EE could save directly data in json format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely understand your issue (for template route ext. is not really matter - you can made it as you want), but possible is that you have *text/html* header instead of *application/json*?

If yes, try to add **terminate="yes"** parameter to JSON plugin:

```
{exp:json:entries channel="news" terminate="yes"}
```

Comment: I was tired, so the answer was confused. Thanks for your response!!!

Comment: I believed that the unique solution was to create a JSON flat file via a script, or a module. Using the JSON plugin that produce a page works too when it's called with http get.